# Condition for Fourier transform to exist?

Tags: complex-numbers, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I came across the following question and had no idea how to begin to answer it. Any tips would be appreciated. Namely what is the condition for Fourier transform to exist?

> Identify the complex values $\alpha$ for wicht the Fourier transform of
>   $$f(t)=\exp(-\alpha|t|)$$
>   exists.

Comment: Do you know $L^p$ spaces?

Comment: never heard of it. I am only a second year Undergraduate Physics student.

Comment: A side note for you to better understand it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=spUNpyF58BY&t

Comment: Break up the integral in the Fourier transform to real and imaginary parts.

Comment: @DionelJaime how would that help?

Comment: The Fourier transform exists for all (measurable) functions $f$ with the property $$\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f(t)|dt<\infty$$ The space of all this functions is $L^1(\mathbb{R})$. Please note that continuous functions are measurable, so this is for your background here not the key point, I guess.

Comment: You have to check, for which values $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$ the integral $\int_{\mathbb{R}}|\exp(-\alpha|t|)|dt$ is finite.